# Highstock: show all two dimension bar of multi series on one tick

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using highstock to show two dimension data of multi series on a chart. But highstock shift bars of series and don't show on one trick!

I used this code:

```
 workData = [
    /* 2009-01-01 */
    [1262048400000, 6, 10],
    [1262134800000, 7.75, 12],
    [1262221200000, 7, 16]
];

freeData = [
    [1262048400000, 10, 12],
    [1262134800000, 13, 16]
];

missionData = [
    [1262134800000, 12, 13]
];

$(function() {



    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange'
        },
        xAxis: {               
            minTickInterval: 24*3600*1000

        },

        series: [{
                name: 'Work',
                data: workData ,
                color: 'green'
            }, {
                name: 'Free',
                data: freeData,
                color:'blue'
            }, {
                name: 'Mission',
                data: missionData ,
                color: 'red'
            }]

    });

});
```

in above code I have 3 series whit two dimension data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `grouping: false` for series, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/E83Ef/1/